# Doctrine Blob Type out of memory error

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, out-of-memory

I have a table which has a Blob field. Sometimes, when loading the overview page for this data (which displays all the data, a usual `SELECT *` statement in the backend) I get an out of memory error - the latest one is shown below (split over multiple lines for reading):

```
request.Critical: Uncaught PHP Exception
Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\OutOfMemoryException: "Error: Allowed memory size of
134217728 bytes exhausted )tried to allocate 1679360 bytes)" at /var/www/html/my_project/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Types/BlobType.php
line 50 ("exception":"[object]
(Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\OutOfMemoryException(code: 0): Error: Allowed memory
size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 1679360 bytes) at /var/www/html/my_project/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Types/BlobType.php:50)")
[]
```

The line 50 it refers to in Doctrine library is

```
48. if (is_string($value)) {
49.    $fp = fopen('php://temp', 'rb+');
50.    fwrite($fp, $value); // Exception occurs here
51.    fseek($fp, 0);
52.    $value = $fp;
53. }
```

How can I deal with this? I haven't found the exact same problem online. Other issues with out of memory exceptions occurring with `fwrite` talk about using streams to write the data - but this would be messing with the Doctrine library which I'm hesitant to do (not fully understanding it myself). Other solutions suggest raising the memory limit in the `php.ini` but wouldn't this just be a temporary solution? Any ideas would be helpful

Comment: What is it that you store as blob?

Comment: @svgrafov It's a PDF - users need to be able to add one to each record (although some records don't have one, in which case it's null).

Comment: @svgrafov I guess actually I should think about moving these across to file storage. Currently I have a web server running on an EC2 instance and the database is an Aurora RDS instance. I'll add an S3 storage bucket to this setup and serve the PDFs from there maybe?

Comment: I am sorry, I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in `SELECT *`. I highly doubt that you need all the table. Display data from it in chunks.
Pagination will help.

**UPD**
Even better idea than pagination - treat files as files. That means to store them as files. And keep only filename(or some other identifier) in your entities.

Comment: I was thinking about doing that - just need to get the time to switch to using pagination. But any idea why it would only happen occasionally?